# How to save a tensorflow model trained in google datalab notebook for offline prediction?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I am using Google Cloud Datalab notebook to train my tensorflow model. I want to save the trained model for offline prediction. However, I am clueless on how to save the model. Should I use any tensorflow model saving method or is there any datalab/google cloud storage specific method to do so? Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any tensorflow model saving method, but I would suggest that you save it into a Google Cloud Storage bucket and not to local disk.  Most tensorflow methods accept Google Cloud Storage paths in place of file names, using the gs:// prefix.

I would suggest using the SavedModelBuilder as it is currently the most portable.  There is an example here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/flowers/trainer/model.py#L393